# Is there a do-release-upgrade history?

Tags: upgrade, do-release-upgrade, update-history

I noticed apport somehow "knows", I started out with 14.04 installation media and upgraded to 16.04 recently... Is there a complete history of all the upgrades I did? And where would I find it?

/var/log/dpkg.log.* only reaches back one year ...

I'm interested in a short overview report with correct dates like:

```
Jul 13th 2014 - install via 14.04 installation media
Nov  2nd 2014 - upgrade to 14.10
Jun 30th 2015 - upgrade to 15.04
Dec 26th 2015 - upgrade to 15.10
May  3rd 2016 - upgrade to 16.04
```

Background: In an old bug report I was asked if I took the screenshot on a specific version. Actually I don't quite well remember anymore. Now I wanted to compare the date of the screenshot to my upgrade history.